# Opencv get accurate real world coordinates from 2 known parallel planes

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

So I have been tinkering a little bit with opencv and I want to be able to use a camera image to get the position of certain objects that are lying flat on plane. These objects are simple shapes such as circles squares etc. They all have the same height of 5cm. To be able to relate real world points to pixels on the camera I painted 4 white squares on the plane with known distances between them.

So the steps I have been taking are:

Initialization:

1. Calibrate my camera using a checkerboard image and save the calibration data.
2. Get the input image. call `cv::undistort` with the calibration data for my camera.
3. Find the center points of the 4 squares in the image and pass that data and the real world coordinates of the squares to the `cv::solvePnP` function. Save the rvec and tvec return parameters.
4. Warp the perspective of the image so you can get a top down view from the image. This is essentially following this tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html
5. Use the resulting image to again find the 4 white squares and then calculate a "pixels per meter" translation constant which can relate a certain amount of difference in pixels between points to the real world distance on the plane where the 4 squares are.

Finding object, This is done after initialization:

1. Get the input image. call `cv::undistort` with the calibration data for my camera.
2. Warp the perspective of the image so you can get a top down view from the image. This is the same as step 4 during initialisation.
3. Find the centerpoint of the object to detect.
4. Since the centerpoint of the object is on a higher plane then where I calibrated I use the following formula to correct this(d = is the pixel offset from the center of the image. camHeight is the cameraHeight I measured by using a tape measure. h is height of the object):

   ```
   d = x - (h * (x / camHeight))
   ```

So here for an illustration how I got this formule:

[image: plane correction]

But still the coordinates are not matching up...

So I am wondering at all if this is the correct. Specifically I have the following questions:

1. Is using `cv::undistort` before using `cv::solvenPnP` correct? `cv::solvePnP` also takes the camera calibration data as input so I'm not sure if I have to pass an undistorted image to it or not.
2. Similar to 1. During Finding object I call `cv::undistort` -> `cv::warpPerspective`. Is this undistort necessary here?
3. Is my calculation to correct for the parallel planes in step 4 correct? I feel like I am missing something but I can't see what. One thing I am wondering is whether I can get the camera height from opencv once solvePnp is done.

I am a newbie to CV so If anything else is totally wrong please also point it out to me.

Thank you for reading this wall of text!

Comment: For your first questions: http://answers.opencv.org/question/98539/undistort-image-before-estimating-pose-using-solvepnp/.  Also I did not understand some parts, will your 4 white squares always be in the scene or you are just using those at initialization?

Comment: @unlut they are always in the scene but I don't use them after getting the pixel per meter value.